# how do I know if a remote user is connected in django?

Tags: python, django, programming-languages, django-templates

how do I know if a remote user is connected in django?, like gmail chat, or facebook chat... I need that in the templates system. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comet is probably what you want. Look at [Orbited](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/django-and-comet/), [Hurricane](http://github.com/ericflo/hurricane) or [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you need just a general idea of who is currently visiting your website, which includes anonymous visitors, use [django-tracking](http://code.google.com/p/django-tracking/) app.

If you need a chat application, or need to know **exactly** who is logged in at any time, this is much more complicated and will require you to know a lot about chat protocols like XMPP and how to use persistent connections with ajax or comet methods.  Some starting projects to look at: [xmpp-psn](http://code.google.com/p/xmpp-psn/) and [django-xmpp](http://code.google.com/p/django-xmpp/)

Also see this web page for a list of non-Django XMPP browser clients: http://xmpp.org/software/clients.shtml